# How do I show user data from Firebase in my Flutter app?

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I’m new to Flutter. How can I retrieve user data from Firebase to my profile page?

My Firebase data contains a name, email, blood type, and a date of birth. And I would like to retrieve this data to my app's profile page.

This is my profile page code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';
import '../Reminder/ui/theme.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //leading: IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Profile',
          style: headingStyle,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.grey[700] : Colors.white,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 120,
                height: 120,
                child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/profile.png")),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              Form(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIconColor: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.black:Colors.white,
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black,)),
                          labelText: "Email",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(LineAwesomeIcons.envelope_1, color:  Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIconColor: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.black:Colors.white,
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black,)),
                          labelText: "Full Name",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(LineAwesomeIcons.user, color:  Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIconColor: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.black:Colors.white,
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black,)),
                          labelText: "Date of Birth",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(LineAwesomeIcons.baby_carriage, color:  Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIconColor: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.black:Colors.white,
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black,)),
                          labelText: "Blood Type",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.bloodtype, color:  Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15,),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                        },
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        child: Text('SIGN OUT'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either `StreamBuilder` or `FutureBuilder`, get the data from `firebase`, and display it accordingly.

**1. StreamBuilder**

When you want to listen to changes constantly, and want the data to get updated without a hot reload/restart

**2. FutureBuilder**

When you want to get the document only once and have no requirement of listening constantly to the change of the document.

1. **Using StreamBuilder**

   ```
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         body: Center(
           child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
             stream:  FirebaseFirestore
                      .instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) //  Your document id which is equal to currentuser
                      .snapshots(),
             builder:
                 (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
               if (snapshot.hasError) {
                 return const Text('Something went wrong');
               }
               if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                 return const Text("Loading");
               }
               Map<String, dynamic> data =
                   snapshot.data!.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
               return Text(data['fullName']); //  your valid data here
             },
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   ```
2. **Using FutureBuilder**

   ```
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         body: Center(
             child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
           future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
               .collection('users')
               .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) //  Your document id which is equal to currentuser
               .get(),
           builder: (_, snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
             if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
               return const Text("Loading");
             }
             Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data()!;
             return Text(data['fullName']); // Your valid data here
           },
         )),
       );
     }
   ```

Comment: FirebaseFirestore query results in future, so technically it is not a good practice to use it within the widget initState. If the user has a slow connection speed it may result in empty data or incomplete data. Stream builders or Future builder are best in this case

Comment: @HassanAli update has been made accordingly  to the industry standards. Thank you for pointing out the same !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stream builder to retrieve data from Firebase and display it to the user on real time. It may have some issues with styling, since I wrote it without any IDE, but I hope you'll get the idea how to get your data from a stream builder.

#### Example

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('your_collection')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    child: Card(
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                          .withOpacity(0.6),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(document['name']),
                          Text(document['email']),
                          Text(document['bloodType']),
                          Text(document['dob']),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            }
          })
    ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: The indentation of the code is completely messed up. Can you fix it, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added the indentation, I hope it helps. It's a basic example of how to get your data from firebase via streambuilder so that the data is always new