# How to display User data from firebase and display in profile in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the user details the user provided on signup from firebase database and
display it in a new page called profile.

I have the profile page design, but I want to know how to retrieve user data such as name age email to the profile page.

I watched different youtube videos and visited a lot of sites, but i cant find the write code for it.

[image: firebase image]

I want to display the above image details in my profile page.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) Firebase is quite well documented and there are tons of tutorials out there already. Without seeing what you already tried and where exactly you got stuck, it is unlikely we'll be able to help better than those already do. For example, here is the documentation on reading a document in Dart/Flutter, which includes an example of how to show it in the UI by using a `StreamBuilder`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show user data from Firebase in my Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75131174/how-do-i-show-user-data-from-firebase-in-my-flutter-app)

Answer (score 0):

I actually did that in a simple way ...

first things first , when I created the collection I set every user id created same as the user id in the authentication (User UID).

then after doing that it becomes more simple.

Whenever you need to retrieve any data for the current user , you will get it using this

```
final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
```

lets say I want to get the user Full Name , I will call this class and send the userId to it , it will return the result needed.

class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
final String documentId;

```
  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(
            "${data['Full Name']}",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
          );
        }
        return Text(
          "Loading...",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

this class will get the user full name for example , and so on.